# C++: How do I prompt a user for input using an int array and char array in the same for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I need my program to prompt the user for Id# and answers (a,b,c,d etc) for 15 students. However it is possible that less than 15 students wrote the quiz. I have to use 2 seperate arrays to store Id #'s and the answers for each student. I have written the following code however it doesn't function properly. If I enter more than 1 letter it exits the loop but if I only enter one letter it works properly. Help would be much appreciated!

```
int id[15];
    char responses[150];

    for (int c = 0; c < 15; c++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Student id: ";
        cin >> id[c];
        if (id[c] < 0) break;
        cout << "Student's responses with no spaces in lower case: ";
        cin >> responses[c];
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have an array of *strings*? E.g. `std::string responses[15]`, or `char responses[15][150]`?

Comment: I am curios as to what `if (id[c] < 0)` is for, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: You have my answered my question. My mistake was using char instead of string array. if (id[c] < 0) is if the user enters a negative student id # it exits the loop. It is beginner programming.